# Как конвертировать текст с формулой в формулу?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

У меня есть текст в ячейке таблицы `=A2*B2`, как сконвертировать этот текст в формулу?

Comment: Очень сильно подозреваю, что у гуглотаблиц нет функции eval.

Comment: И почему метка api? С помощью чего надо сделать?

Comment: Возможно, [ответы на схожий вoпрос на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12036726/12506088) будет полезны... если тут про аппскрипты речь. Еще, см. в документации Sheets API про [ValueInputOption  `USER_ENTERED`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#writing).

Comment: @Qwertiy, нормального интерпретатора формул в исполняемый код не существует. Но есть для Excel.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете воспользоваться Google Apps Script для такого преобразования

```js
/**
 * @param {globalThis.SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet} sheet
 */
function activateTextToFormulas_(sheet) {
  sheet.createTextFinder('^=').matchFormulaText(false).useRegularExpression(true)
    .findAll()
    .forEach(range => range.setValue(range.getValue()));
}
function run() {
  activateTextToFormulas_(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet());
}
```

Результат работы https://youtu.be/Qz79zktJ42g